# How do you add miner address so that it can mint tokens?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, erc-721

I have ERC721 that I'm making.

```
function mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyMinter returns (bool) {
    _mint(to, tokenId);
    return true;
}
```

How can I add an address so that it is able to mint? Can I simply write a function that calls addMinter(address)? Or do I have to do it in the constructor?

Comment: What does "it" refer to? Who is doing the minting?

Answer (score 0):

An minter can call to [addMinter](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/access/roles/MinterRole.sol#L26)

Something like this should work

```
token.methods.addMinter(newMinterAddress)
    .send({ from: existingMinter })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in feature of ERC-721, you will need to use an extension.

Xcert, the contract for 0xcert has this feature.

https://github.com/0xcert/framework/blob/master/packages/0xcert-ethereum-xcert-contracts/src/contracts/xcert.sol

Here is the relevant code

```
  /**
   * @dev Creates a new Xcert.
   * @param _to The address that will own the created Xcert.
   * @param _id The Xcert to be created by the msg.sender.
   * @param _imprint Cryptographic asset imprint.
   */
  function create(
    address _to,
    uint256 _id,
    bytes32 _imprint
  )
    external
    hasAbilities(ABILITY_CREATE_ASSET)
  {
    super._create(_to, _id);
    idToImprint[_id] = _imprint;
  }
```

And the abilities are tracked using `Abilitable`. You will set the minter for this other entity.